# Is "that" in - "all the information that you want" - wrong?

Tags: pronouns

I was spotting errors on a site But this one problem confuses me

> You can get all the information that you want in this book.

The error was show to be "that."

So, the correct sentence was this:

> You can get all the information you want in this book.

Was "that" wrongly used there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker, I would say there is no difference, "that" certainly gets used in those types of situations

> All the things **that** you need
>   Some of the things **that** you like
>   Somethings **that** have fur

the **that** is optional which is probably why it's marked as an error since **that** can be dropped without lose of meaning.

Comment: Your statement that in this case (and in other cases) it's possible to omit "that" is also mentioned in English courses. Or at least I remember to have heard about this possibility in my high school's English courses.

Comment: And by the way, do you think that my previous comment is grammatically and semantically correct?

Comment: Yes, your comment and your comment question are both correct and both sound native.  I was going to respond "We all have to learn somewhere"

Comment: Furry Somethings. Sounds like a new fad.Collect them all.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  We're too late, could have made a fortune: [Furbies](https://www.hasbro.com/en-us/brands/furby)